# Bogomol'nyi-Prasad-Sommerfield (BPS) limit

Tags: gauge-theory, magnetic-monopoles

When discussing the 't Hooft-Polyakov monopole and establishing the BPS bound, one also discusses BPS states and Bogomol'nyi-Prasad-Sommerfield limit. This limit sets $\lambda \to 0$ in the potential $$V(\Phi)=\dfrac{\lambda}{4} \left( \Phi^{(a)} \Phi^{(a)} - v^2 \right)^2,$$
with $\Phi$ the Higgs field, with the subscript $(a)$ denoting its component in adjoint space.

How can this limit be consistent with the development leading to the existence of monopoles in the first place? We need a non-zero potential to have spontaneous symmetry breaking, and this limit seems to kill the very reason for which it was considered.